# Software to visualize web traffic

Tags: windows, internet

I want the software to **visualize web traffic in real-time** and provide me with **geeky** data. The more data, the better.

Preferences:

- Open Source
- Platform: Windows

Comment: How would you like the results presented to you (graphs, tables, what?)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is your server running on Windows, since you are asking for that? If not (which automatically implies that you are not going to run that software on your server - something you may not wish anyhow **but you don't tell us**), how do think it should collect the stats from your server?. Please take a step back and reread your question to check if it makes sense to someone who does not know your setup (my 'verdict': it does not, as it is now).

Comment: When you've followed Jan's advice and see which way it can work and what you really need, take a second round and define "provide me geeky data". Either the data already have been geeky, or the software has to fake some :) Honestly: As it currently stands, the question can hardly receive quality answers. A guide to check for [edit]ing your question with would be: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: This would be a good question, if you would be a bit more specific as asked by the comments above. Please do, so I can upvote the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the developers console in your browser or use FireBug. Go to the "Network" tab, activate the panel and refresh the website. This is for a "client" in geek term.

For a **server and client** , install lib pcap and use a tool that can "watch" the network traffic like ngrep or tcpdump ( for Windows I think wireshark?).

All of those tools provide the finest  fancy and geeky data. (will add links and more later)