# Like Firefox/Chrome's "Network" viewer but for entire OS. A Firebug or Web Inspector for all web traffic

Tags: windows, linux, network-monitor, http

I am looking for a way to see any images or XHR data that any apps on my **Windows** or **Linux** OS might be transmitting.

Maybe I don't understand something crucial about the OSI stack, but I'm looking for something like Firebug, but for all browsers and apps at once.

**Fiddler** and **Wireshark** don't show internet traffic like firefox/chrome's "Inspect Tools" does, this is what I am looking for. (Both are based on the GUI concept that Firebug once had).

---

This question is [similar to mine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16880/14829) but has been closed.

Comment: What __exactly__ are you looking for that Wireshark doesn't show? Like something doesn't make a great question.